# error while writing results ping host to file

Tags: python

I'm writing some code in python 3 to execute these actions:

1. reads to file of hosts and execute ping each host
2. write to file the inaccessible IP hosts

```
import subprocess
fp = open('ip_host.txt') # open file ip host
text_file = open("result_ping.txt", "w") # open file result ping host 

for ip in fp.readlines():
    response = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe",ip])
response.wait()

result = []
if response.poll():
    res_down = (ip + " - is down")
else:
    res_up = (ip + " - is up")

    result.append(res_down)
text_file.write(result)

fp.close() 
text_file.close()
```

but when executing code show error:

```
    result.append(res_down)
NameError: name 'res_down' is not defined
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The way to fix this is to think about what you're trying to do.

Comment: The reason you're getting an error is because `res_down` is defined within the `if`, but not the `else`.

Comment: `append(res_down)` where it is actually defined, not where `res_up` is

Comment: You never use `res_up`, by the way. Do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Overall, you can clean up your code considerably.

Plus, I think you should wait *per IP*, not for the last line in the file.

```
import subprocess
with open('ip_host.txt') as fp, open("result_ping.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for ip in fp:
        response = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe",ip])
        response.wait()

        if response.poll():
            text_file.write(ip + " - is down")
        else:
            res_up = (ip + " - is up")
        text_file.write("\n")
```